# Android: фоновый сервис

Tags: android, service

Здравствуйте. Нигде не могу найти точной информации по этому вопросу. Как можно убедиться, что сервис всегда будет запущен. 
Как запускаться при перезагрузке телефона все ясно.
А вот что делать, когда пользователь скачал и запустил приложение, если при запуске приложения запускать и сервис? Не запустит ли Андроид вторую копию сервиса?
И как ставить сервис на таймаут?

Answer (score 4):

Запустить две копии сервиса нельзя. При повторной попытке запуска будет вызван onStartCommand (onStart для старых андроидов) для запущенного сервиса, и onCreate вызываться не будет.

Гарантировать то, что сервис будет всегда запущен нельзя. Различные флаги не помогают. при нехватке ресурсов сервис все равно может быть выгружен системой.

Можно при старте сервиса создавать в AlarmManager'е событие повторного запуска сервиса через несколько минут. Например в onStartCommand:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);//через пять минут
servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
   SERVICE_REQUEST_CODE, intent,//SERVICE_REQUEST_CODE - уникальный int сервиса
   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),servicePendingIntent);
```

Даже если вы прибьете его в работающих приложениях, сервис перезапустится.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так, чтобы сервис не грохался ни при каких условиях, достаточно `в OnStartComand()` сделать сервис с параметром "foregraund", но для этого придётся сделать уведомление,которое нельзя будет удалить и оно постоянно будет висеть в tray, это сделано в целях безопасности,чтобы пользователь знал,что есть посторонние сервисы.

Добавь эту строку в `OnStartComand()`

```
startForeground (int id, Notification notification)
```

и сервис никогда не грохнется,только при Exception или, когда телефон вырубится.